# convert array of int ([3,6]) to [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Eg: - Array of integers - [3,3,6] to [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]

```
lazy var arrCount = 3
lazy var numberCount = [Int]()
lazy var someArr = [SomeArr]()

for i in 0 ..< self!. arrCount.count {
  self?.numberCount.append(self!.arrCount[I].someArr!.count)
}
print(self?.numberCount.count) // now response based on above example prints [3,3,6]
```

> Response [3,3,6] - [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map` method.

```
var arr = [3, 6];
print(arr.map { Array(1...$0) })
```

Output

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: @SaiKishore, you mean the total 9?

Comment: Then just use a method which access the array item by index.